# jQuery Change top value on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am hoping to create an effect similar to [this one](http://playgroundinc.com/work/grammys/) further down the page, in the 'Designing For 20-Somethings' section. 
The effect is essentially to get a long image to change the css top value within a device such as a MacBook or iPhone, so it appears as though the image within the device is also scrolling whilst the user is scrolling the website.

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qja2Ljkw/5/) to show how far I've got, but this doesn't work well on resize or when initially loaded.

This is some of the code I am using below

```
var yOffset =  $element.offset().top - ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height()/diviser)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get this window to scroll inside your macbook screen? the example your pointing to is just using 4 divs with background colors and fixed positions to create the gold border. Is that what you're trying to do? I'm afraid what you want to accomplish isn't clear from your questions or your fiddle.

Comment: @GreggDuncan I've updated the question, hopefully this explains what I am trying to achieve better. I'm talking about the MacBooks and iPhones further down the screen where the image inside changes the top value. I've also created a fiddle that is similar to the example, but doesn't exactly work correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Changes the top value". The 'table' and 'mobile' divs are positioned Absolutely. then the image inside is given a style="top: -180px;" which moves them up so it appears you've scrolled down inside the tablet or phone. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @GreggDuncan Yes, as you can see, the further down you scroll, the css top value keeps decreasing, and if you scroll back up, the top value starts to go back up as well. It's not simply a matter of putting `top: -180px;`

Answer (score 0):

OK I see it now. But the movement is so subtle i didn't even notice it. It looks to be a lot of work for something that is pretty much unnoticeable. It appears he's changing the top position of the image based on some percentage change of the full window scroll but only when the image is inside the viewport.

Just off the top of my head (completely untested) something like this would scroll the image up and 1/4 the speed the window would scroll;

```
var mobiletop = $('.mobile').position().top;
var scrollfactor = 4;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > mobiletop){
        var imgtop = $('.mobile img').position().top -  (($(window).scrollTop() - mobiletop)/scrollfactor);

        $('.mobile img').css('top', imgtop + 'px');
}
```

Comment: It also increases the `top` value when the you scroll up, and it seems to be doing it at a much higher speed than the window scrolling.